# Why Firebase global import is lighter than specific ones?

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, apk, filesize

I am making an Ionic app.
I use ionic-angular 3.9.2 and firebase 4.6.2 as dependencies.

In multiple files, I am importing Firebase globally, this way:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

However, I recently noticed in [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) that this includes every Firebase features (6, excluding the core).

It is said that we can import features individually.
So if I only need the "auth" feature, the following is advocated:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; // (Importing Firebase core.)
import'firebase/auth';               // (Importing Firebase auth only.)
```

Now, it should only import one feature, the auth one.

So I tried and replaced every occurences of my global imports with the latter.
However, doing so resulted in my apk being 1.2MB **heavier**!

I stashed these modifications and went back to using global imports everywhere and noticed the 1.2M reduction in my apk size.

Why is that so?